# SVO extraction from a sentence using Python

Tags: python, nlp

I need to extract Subject, Verb and the Object from a sentence given by user using python. Please advice me.

Comment: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html

Comment: Advice: read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

Just parse your sentences with a parser that supports grammatical dependencies. For example, parsing the sentence "The children play football" with Stanford Parser will return the following set of grammatical dependencies:

```
det(children-2, the-1)
nsubj(play-3, children-2)
root(ROOT-0, play-3)
dobj(play-3, football-4)
```

The dependencies you're looking for is `nsubj` and `dobj`. Of course, if your sentence contains more than one transitive verb, you're going to get more pairs of `nsubj`, `dobj` dependencies. There is a [Python interface](https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp/) to call the Stanford parser programmatically from your scripts.